Spresense で WiFi Add-onボードとLTE拡張ボードの同時使用は可能か？
Spresense本体とLTE拡張ボードを使ってMQTT通信でAWSにデータ送信しています。
上記組み合わせに、Wifi Add-onボードを追加することは可能でしょうか？
Wifi Add-onボードを追加したい理由として、Spresenseのデバッグ用途を想定しています。

こちらに、Arduino環境でWiFiとLTEを動かすサンプルがあるようです。
これを見るとArduino環境では同時に動作させることができそうです。
https://github.com/TomonobuHayakawa/Spresense-Playground/tree/master/sketches/AccessPoint/wifi-lte/
